# Alias for a shell script

Tags: shell, unix, alias

I need `wget` to be always used with `--no-check-certificate` option. This can be accomplished by typing the following line in a Unix terminal:

```
alias wget='wget --no-check-certificate'
```

However, when I execute shell scripts `.sh` that include `wget` command, the original `wget` is used not the aliased one. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Consider including your `alias` command in either of `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`

Answer (score 3):

You have to ensure your alias is defined, where the Shell-script is also sourcing it. If you are using Bash and the Shell-script is using `/bin/bash` as interpreator, putting into file .bashrc might bei a good idea.

However,  `--no-check-certificate` is in about 99.9% of all cases a very bad idea as SSL is there for a reason.

Also I recommend not to overwrite common commands with custom aliases as this might change behavior of tools a script is relying on in unexpected way. I really recommend to fix up the environment so you don't need this dirty hack.

Comment: `wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/ampl/mp/archive/1.3.0.tar.gz` should output a `1.3.0.tar.gz` file, but is outputting a `1.3.0` file. Is this issue caused by the `--no-check-certificate` option?

Comment: No it is not and it's also not true

Comment: `wget --no-check-certificate https://github.com/ampl/mp/archive/1.3.0.tar.gz` makes a `1.3.0.tar.gz` file on linux, but makes a `1.3.0` file in `msys`. Why? The output should be `1.3.0.tar.gz` otherwise the next lines of my `.sh` script break.

Comment: If you need a exact file name use -O file/—output-document=file and for gods sake: Read the documentation of wget.

Comment: Without using `--no-check-certificate` option I get the `ERROR: cannot verify github.com's certificate`. So how can I resolve the issue without using `--no-check-certificate`

Comment: So `-O file/—output-document=file` is an option for `wget`? should I replace the two `file`s with something?

Comment: Step back from your keyboard. Think about reading the documentation of wget and than use either -O <outputfilename> OR —output-document=<outputfilename>. Once you have thought about this, think why your wget cannot verify github's SSL certificate instead of ignoring. Most likely your environment is somehow broken or there is a man-in-the-middle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135941/discussion-between-frlan-and-admia).